# Assigning a tuple to two array fields

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I just noticed a behaviour in python I don't understand.
Imagine the following code:

```
myArray  = [0] * 10   
myTuple = (1,1)
```

Now I want to assign the two values in my tuple to two fields in my array. Since Python allows to change muliple values at once I tried

```
myArray[2:3] = myTuple
```

What I expect for myArray is

```
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

But what I actually get is

```
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Who can explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: what you mean is probably: `myArray[2:4] = myTuple`.

Comment: Check also [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2314737)

Comment: It's not wholly clear whether what's surprising you is that: 1. slice assignment can change the length of a list; or: 2. `[2:3]` only slices a single element. Both are already explained elsewhere, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the length of the slice `[2:3]` is 1, the element at index `2` (slicing in Python is exclusive of the `stop` index, so element at index `3` is not included). And you are trying to insert 2 elements in it, hence it inserts the second element after index 2, increasing the size of the array by 1. You need to do -

```
myArray[2:4] = myTuple
```

Demo -

```
>>> myArray  = [0] * 10
>>> myTuple = (1,1)
>>> myArray[2:3] = myTuple
>>> len(myArray)
11
>>> myArray  = [0] * 10
>>> myTuple = (1,1)
>>> myArray[2:4] = myTuple
>>> len(myArray)
10
```

Comment: Oh yes...sure....Sometimes you just can't see mistakes in the own code.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`myArray[2:3]` is actually a list containing one element (which is the third element in the list).

You're simply inserting 2 elements there, and that's increases the list's size. You probably want to do:

```
myArray[2:4] = myTuple
```